# Where do I create a ticket for pid documentation?

Tags: ros, pid, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[I'm returning to ROS for my latest robot project.  I'm appreciating it greatly and want to participate in improving it.  Right now I'm in an especially good position to report issues from a "new user" perspective.]

At the moment, I'd like to submit a report of errors in the pid wiki page.
http://wiki.ros.org/pid

1. I checked the issue trackers.  I see "On a wiki page for a package or stack there should be a link at the bottom pointing to where to file tickets."  No such luck.  (Maybe I'm missing it?)
2. I looked through the list of common organizations on GitHub for ROS packages.  "ROS Controls" seems like the closest fit but I didn't find any hits when I searched it for "pid" so I doubt that's it.
3. Searching for "pid" stuff on ROS Answers gets a lot of hits...for process IDs.
4. I'm reporting fairly simple documentation issues so I doubt anyone would have reported them already and it seems a bit too trivial to blast the mailing list.
5. I see the author for the package but I also see the warnings not to contact maintainers directly.  I also know how disruptive it can be to handle individual e-mail requests like this.

So...here I am.  Help?  I want to address the immediate issues with pid but I'm also interested in guidance on doing this better in the future.

Thank you.

--kyler

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240250/where-do-i-create-a-ticket-for-pid-documentation?/) by [kylerlaird](https://answers.ros.org/users/23170/kylerlaird/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2016-07-24

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry I'm slow to answer. I'm just discovering that the issue tracker in bitbucket is OFF by default- but it's enabled now. So you can submit a new issue there:
https://bitbucket.org/AndyZe/pid/issues?status=new&status=open

Or just send me an email as gvdhoorn suggested. (andyz at utexas dot edu)

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2016-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0